# Is there any affordable entry level FPGA development board that Matlab supports?

Tags: matlab, development-environment, fpga

I am just wondering if if this is possible? I found this board:

http://www.altera.com/products/devkits/altera/kit-cyc2-2C20N.html

There is no mention of Matlab support.
Either way,
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://www.mathworks.nl/fpga-design/fpga-development-board-simulink.html

Comment: What parts of Matlab do you expect "support" for?

Comment: Dennis: This is all I could find as you indicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfacing with Matlab is not specific to FPGA board, but FPGA design tools (synthesis and place & route). Both major FPGA vendors - Xilinx and Altera - support Matlab. Xilinx in its [System Generator](http://www.mathworks.com/fpga-design/simulink-with-xilinx-system-generator-for-dsp.html), and Altera in its [DSP Builder](http://www.altera.com/products/ip/altera/t-alt-matlab.html).
The design flow is approximately as follows:

1. You write your Matlab code, given the restrictions of FPGA tools and FPGA device you're targeting. For example FPGA devices have limited amount of memory, few KByte to few MByte, depending on the device.
2. You compile your Matlab code. Under the hood the code will be converted to a hardware description language.
3. FPGA tools will synthesize and place & route the code and generate a bitstream
4. You program the bitstream into your FPGA.